# opening output filestreams with string names

Tags: c++, csv, filepath, ofstream

Hi I have some C++ code that uses user defined input to generate file-names for some output files:

```
std::string outputName = fileName;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    outputName.pop_back();
}
std::string outputName1 = outputName;
std::string outputName2 = outputName;
outputName.append(".fasta");
outputName1.append("_Ploid1.fasta");
outputName2.append("_Ploid2.fasta");
```

Where fileName could be any word the user can define with .csv after it e.g. '~/Desktop/mytest.csv'

The code chomps .csv off and makes three filenames / paths for 3 output streams.

It then creates them and attempts to open them:

```
std::ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open(outputName.c_str());
std::ofstream outputFile1;
outputFile1.open(outputName1.c_str());
std::ofstream outputFile2;
outputFile2.open(outputName2.c_str());
```

I made sure to pass the names to open as const char* with the c_str method, however if I test my code by adding the following line:

`std::cout <<  outputFile.is_open() << " " << outputFile1.is_open() << " " << outputFile2.is_open() << std::endl;`

and compiling and setting fineName as "test.csv". I successfully compile and run, however,

Three zeros's are printed to screen showing the three filestreams for output are not in fact open. Why are they not opening? I know passing strings as filenames does not work which is why I thought conversion with c_str() would be sufficient.

Thanks,
Ben W.

Comment: And you provide absolute paths to these files? If you output the actual filenames, are they correct then?

Comment: They are correct - the files don't yet exist, they should be created and then written to.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is likely to be due to the path beginning with `~`, which isn't expanded to `/{home,Users}/${LOGNAME}`.

- [ifstream open file C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769745/78845)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4891126/78845) to [How to create a folder in the home directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4891006/78845) may be of use to you.

Unfortunately, there is no standard, portable way of finding out exactly why `open()` failed:

- [Detecting reason for failure to open an ofstream when fail() is true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/960541/78845)

> I know passing strings as filenames does not work which is why I thought conversion with `c_str()` would be sufficient.

[`std::basic_ofstream::open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) ***does*** accept a `const std::string &` (since C++11)!

Comment: Re the last point: only in C++11.  Older compilers might not support it.